# How to create a DLL which exports a callback function in C using VS 2008?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, dll, callback

I dont know how can I create a DLL which can export a callback function in C.

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Can anybody help me with a good sample code or link or tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Create DLL project (in Visual Studio). (2) List your exported functions in [*.def file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of your DLL. (3) Compile your DLL project.

Comment: thank you for your reply.. but can you point me to a good tutorial link or explain by some sample code or with some more details step by step.. I am sort of a newbie.. thanks in advance!

Comment: @mahendraliya: What have you tried already? Did you ever run Visual Studio? Did you ever create Visual Studio projects? Did you open project's properties? Did you add files to the project?

Answer (score 1):

Given you have the following function you want to export:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CallWndProc( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );
```

If your DLL is called HookDLL for example then you create a file called HookDLL.def with the following contents:

```
LIBRARY HookDLL
EXPORTS
  CallWndProc @1
```

This is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). Your alternative is with __declspec(dllexport) which is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx).